Public experience site and safe-calling Apex without Sharing
my company security department has concerns about the Experience Page with Screen Flow and Apex without sharing class, and I am looking whether a different approach is possible.
Domain
Experience Page is completely public (no restriction for IP, etc.) and does not require logging into the user account, we are using a default Guest Account (only read and create permissions). Guest Users will get an email, containing the URL to that Page with a unique URL parameter, let's call it uniqueToken (www.salesforce.com/expPage?uniqueToken=tokenValue).
The tokenValue we are sending is encrypted with Apex's Crypto class, and upon entering that Experience Page, we must decrypt it with Apex as well before we process it further in Screen Flow. The privateKey is stored as a Custom Setting record, and Guest User does not have added permission for it. The decrypted tokenValue is then returned into the Flow, and used as a parameter to query some records afterwards with Flow's Get Record elements. Very similar to what is in official documentation here and here, without Aura though.
Potential security problem?
Because we need to call Apex, both for decryption and accessing the privateKey, we used Apex without sharing class with one Invocable Method to be called by that Flow. Unfortunately, the Security Department does not like that the Public Page is directly calling any code in without sharing context, and wants us to investigate if we can find workarround to it.
Potential solution idea
I do not see any convincing solution to that honestly. The only thing I can think of is to use an LWC Component inside that Screen Flow as an intermediate layer that would call the Apex instead, to separate transactions as much as possible:

Page opened ->
Screen Flow reads URL uniqueToken parameter ->
Screen Flow calls the LWC ->

LWC shows waiting spinner and calls Promise to Apex ->

Apex (still must be without sharing) decrypts and get required records from database ->
Apex returns records into LWC ->


LWC fills Screen Flow's variable and opens Flows next Screen element with FlowNavigationNextEvent ->


Screen Flow proceeds further

Is it any better?
To be honest, I do not see how that approach would be more secure in a meaningful way. We are faking asynchronous here and adding some more layers of separated, independent transactions, so maybe primitive hijack/XSS vulnerabilities would be a bit harder (are they?). But, instead of using just Flow and Apex, we are using Flow, Apex, and LWC, so we are adding one potential attack vector if Salesforce would mess something with security on the components they provide.

I think you are spot on on the fact that it doesnt really make a difference. Its a guest site for a reason, I think the thing you could ensure is  that all of the logic is hidden behind that security implementation where you decrypt a key and use that key to allow or deny access

For me, the most secure approach would be to make the Apex invocable method do the necessary queries of records, ensuring permissions are considered, so the private key is never seen in a potentially insecure context.
